# Getting an A callout was unsuccessful error for external object

Tags: apex, batch, externalobjects

Please assist I'm getting the following error while running a test class for external object : System.UnexpectedException: A callout was unsuccessful because of pending uncommitted work related to a process, flow, or Apex operation. Commit or roll back the work, and then try again. Never written a test class for external objects before(.
Here is the main batch :

```
public class FailedFTDBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, user_uid__c FROM sf_failed_ftds__x';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sf_failed_ftds__x> records) {
    Set<String> uids = new Set<String>();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (sf_failed_ftds__x failedDeposits : records) {
        uids.add(failedDeposits.user_uid__c);
    }

    for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Account.exness_client_uid__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.exness_client_uid__c IN :uids]) {
        Task newTask = new Task(
                WhatId = opp.Id,
                OwnerId = opp.OwnerId,
                ActivityDate = Date.today(),
                Subject = 'Failed Deposit, please check',
                Description = 'Failed'
        );
        taskList.add(newTask);
    }

    if (!taskList.isEmpty()) {
        Database.insert(taskList, false);
    }
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
```

}

Here is the test suite

```
@IsTest
private class FailedFTDBatchTestSuite {
@TestSetup
private static void testData() {

    List<Account> accountList = TestDataFactory.generateTestAccounts(2, 'FailedFTD_TestAccount');
    accountList[0].exness_client_uid__c = '123';
    accountList[1].exness_client_uid__c = '1234';

    update accountList;

    System.debug('Account ' + accountList);

    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>{
        new Opportunity(Name = '123', AccountId = accountList[0].Id),
        new Opportunity(Name = '1234', AccountId = accountList[1].Id)
    };
    Database.insert(oppList, false);
    System.debug('Opportunity ' + oppList);

    List<sf_failed_ftds__x> sfFailedFtds = new List<sf_failed_ftds__x>{
            new sf_failed_ftds__x(invoice_status__c = 'Rejected', user_uid__c = '123'),
            new sf_failed_ftds__x(invoice_status__c = 'Canceled', user_uid__c = '1234')
    };
    Database.insertImmediate(sfFailedFtds);
    System.debug('Failed FTDBatch test data '+ sfFailedFtds);
}

@IsTest
private static void testBehavior() {
    System.Test.startTest();

    List<sf_failed_ftds__x> sfFailedF = [
        SELECT Id, user_uid__c
        FROM sf_failed_ftds__x
    ];
    System.debug('failed FTDs ' + sfFailedF);

    List<Opportunity> opp = [
        SELECT Id, AccountId
        FROM Opportunity
    ];

    Database.executeBatch(new FailedFTDBatch());
    System.Test.stopTest();

    List<Task> checkTask = [
        SELECT Id, WhatId, OwnerId
        FROM Task
    ];

    System.assertEquals(opp[0].Id, checkTask[0].WhatId, 'Checking the Task');
}
```

}

Comment: You need to restructure your runtime code to use a selector class/layer for the query for the external objects, then the testmethod injects a mock selector that returns mocked external objects - that is, you don't do DML to insert the external objects. There are many examples if you search on "testmethod external objects"

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, thanks